# Hikari with Postgress datasource

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

What is the correct way to define hikari datasource in spring boot application ?
We are using this which works but I am not sure what PG datasource is used

```
datasource.test.jdbcUrl=url
datasource.test.username=username
datasource.test.password=pass
datasource.test.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.test.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
datasource.test.maximum-pool-size=5
```

with

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(props);
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

according to hikari [README](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) they are using ds with properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("dataSourceClassName", "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
props.setProperty("dataSource.user", "test");
props.setProperty("dataSource.password", "test");
props.setProperty("dataSource.databaseName", "mydb");
...
```

where is defined PG datasource.

Is there any different between this two definition or I should used second one which is in Hikari wiki ? First one also use PGSimpleDataSource ?

Comment: There isn no difference. Don't use a test query, that is only for non JDBC 4 drivers.

Comment: so first one also use PGSimpleDataSource ?

Comment: If you properly consrtuct a datasource from that it will.

Comment: I disagree when  I debug first example using HikariDataSource

Comment: Then you aren't properly constructing it.

Comment: what do you mean, I am using constructor from hikari wiki and I update it in question. I don't how it can used PG datasource in first example

Comment: As stated that isn't the proper way. You should use the Spring Boot helpers to create the datasource, if you have a single one you can just use the `spring.datasource` properties else use the `DataSourceProperties` and `DataSourceBuilder` to create it.

Comment: I can no use spring.datasource because we have more datasources in application and we want to create it in our way as bean. So never mind I will find difference between PGSimpleDataSource vs HikariDataSource and check which one to use

Comment: YOu can still use the properties and builder as explain din the Spring Boot reference guide to properly configure it. You shouldn't manually create the datasource. Also both will use `HikariDataSource` as that is your pool it will delegate everything else to the Postgres stuff.

Comment: I am using similar example as here: https://github.com/ehsaniara/spring-boot-multi-data-source which works in our application like 6 years and which I dont want to rewrite

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use the default as advertised by Spring Boot in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources). Instead of manually configuring it (as you are doing now). But alas.